Caching user data (db entity) in RESTful services
Before asking my question, I would like to note that I have done some research for similar posts and I have not been able to find a clear answer so I decided to write my question in here.
I am trying to improve my Restful services by applying the best practices. I noticed that I found specific user information by username/userId under the most of the endpoints that I created. Generally, I need to find the user identity first for the rest of the processing, (to get user-related resource). I consider caching user data but in this case I am afraid of violating REST principles and turning them into session based web applications.
Do I have to re-identify the user by making a db request every time the server receives a request to continue providing my service as a Restful service? or Can I use cache (user model in my case) to send a faster response to the request sender?


I can not put user email or db related user id into JWT because user information must stay confidential. I know that JWT can be decoded, everyone can read its contents.

The level of confidentiality you mention is usually not needed. In the vast majority of cases the site is fine with the user getting their userid or some other resource id. e.g. I can just get your userid as 9139357.
In my previous architectural design, I would put the user id in JWT or other types of Token. And cache this data on the server side so that you can get the user login information quickly and easily. I think this is one of the best practices.
In Java you can implement the above scenario roughly through the following process:

Parsing the JWT carried by the request through a custom filter to get the user id.
Get the user's information from the cache (or DB, it's up to you) and map it to an object.
Store the user information in a ThreadLocal object.
At any stage in the flow of this request, read the contents of the ThreadLocal to get the user information.
Note that you need to clear out the information inside the ThreadLocal at the end of the request to prevent problems arising from thread multiplexing.


replenishment：
If you don't want the user to get the id data, then there is another way, that is to store SessionId in JWT. That is to generate the UUID at login time, use it as Key and user information as Value. put it into cache or database. Then put this SessionId into a Token and give it to the client.
If you want to limit the number of clients logging in, you can add an additional index to the user ID to make it easier to look up the number of active sessions, so that the user can only get one JWT with the UUID in it.
As for your mention of the need for ThreadLocal, this is a common practice. It's also good to use the SecurityContextHolder provided by Spring Security, it's more reliable (it's also stored underneath via ThreadLocal) it's up to you.
But I still don't understand why you are so resistant to the user getting the ID of the resource, it's quite common practice in Restful interface design to get the corresponding resource by its id.

If user id an integer, it can be guessed. Someone can make a call by entering random user id at the db level. Thus, I do not want to expose user id (which is related with the row). I can use surrogate key instead\
You are proposing to store user information in a ThreadLocal object. Do I really need that? I can access user object from any class implementing Authentication interface for example, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

Then you can replace the user id via UUID by using something like SessionId.
ThreadLocal is not required, it is just a simple implementation. It's also good to use the SecurityContextHolder provided by SpringSecurity. It's a much better implementation, it's up to you.


Do I have to re-identify the user every time the server receives a request to continue providing my service as a Restful service? or Can I use cache (user model in my case) to send a faster response to the request sender?

Entirely up to you.  REST only says:

each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request

What your implementation does with a request that has all of the necessary information is detail hidden behind the facade that makes your service look like a boring 1990s web site.

I can not put user email or db related user id into JWT because user information must stay confidential. I know that JWT can be decoded, everyone can read its contents.
